# JavaScript Prototype Example

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am trying to use the prototype feature with example code that I have from another site.

I have simplified the code and listed it below. When I use it I get the following error: TypeError: this.createChart is not a function. I do not get this error on jsfiddle, only when I am trying to implement the code my site.

My working jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/56vjtv3d/76

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
 function Meteogram(A,B) {
      this.A = A;
      this.B = B;
      this.createChart(); 
    }

    Meteogram.prototype.createChart = function() {
      alert('test');
      //Will do other stuff here
    };
```

Comment: This code (plus `new Meteogram()`, of course) is working for me, and I'm not seeing any errors in the JSFiddle.

Comment: I pasted this in console .. it works.

Comment: You have to show us the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine, you are probably not initializing your object/s correctly

Your Meteogram function is known as "Object Constructor" and its usefull to create several similar objects, and to create new objects from this constructor you need to use the *new* keyword

**We already have this:**

```
function Meteogram(A,B) {
    this.A = A;
    this.B = B;
    this.createChart(); 
}

Meteogram.prototype.createChart = function() {
    alert('test');
    //Will do other stuff here
}
```

now..

**This will work**:

```
var m = new Meteogram('a', 'b');
// Now m is an instance of Meteogram !!
```

**This won't**:

```
var m = Meteogram('a', 'b');
// Uncaught TypeError: this.createChart is not a function(…)
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I was not initializing correctly in my code. Thank you for your help!